# Максимальный отрицательный элемент массива

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив размером nxn, элементы которого целые числа, размерность которого вводится пользователем. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как узнать максимальный отрицательный элемент?

Comment: @rdx, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Создайте массив размером указанный пользователем. Заведите переменную того же типа, что и элементы массива. Присвойте первый элемент массива этой переменной. Через цикл переберите все элементы массива и сравнивайте с переменной, если элемент массива окажется меньше чем значение переменной, то изменить значение переменной на значение элемента массива. Когда цикл закончится, в переменной будет самое маленькое число. Если оно окажется больше нуля, можно сказать, что отрицательных элементов нет.

Comment: @pincher1519, вы не правы. Надо в цикле перебирать все элементы, пока не наткнемся на отрицательный, значение которого и присваиваем нашей max_negative, первоначально инициализированной нулем, например. Затем в цикле продолжаем искать отрицательные элементы и если они > max_negative, то обновляем значение. После цикла получаем либо искомое значение либо 0 (тоесть отриц. элементов в массиве нет). Код не привожу из педагогических соображений (хоть и не препод сам), т.к. стюденты окончательно обленились :)

Comment: @pincher1519, @MDJHD: можно проще. Поскольку все искомые элементы отрицательны, за начальное значение можно взять 0, и не искать отдельно первый отрицательный элемент.

Comment: @VladD, то ли я вас не правильно понял, то ли я не совсем понятно выразил свою мысль. Я ведь и предлагаю изначально первоначально инициализировать max_negative = 0

Comment: @vladd, Так я и не предлагал искать. Первый элемент берётся за основу, а потом уже поиск. Но согласен, на итерациях в условиях можно сократить, если задачу рассматривать буквально, инициализировав переменную нулем, а не первым значением элемента массива.

Comment: Можете использовать этот код, он верный. Но как ответ я его не отправлю, а то господа комментирующие заминусуют меня за использование LINQ в учебном задании, как, возможно, и вас преподаватель :)

    int[,] arr = new int[2, 2] {{1,2}, {-3, 4}};
    int max = arr.Cast<int>().Where(x => x < 0).Max();

Comment: @VladD, хотя какова вероятность, что первый элемент и будет являться самым малым отрицательным? И тогда не будет никакого выигрыша по скорости :-) У условии же не сказано, какие будут числа, может только отрицательные будут вводиться.

Comment: @Jofsey интересный вариант (для меня, как не знающего сишарп), но если хотите помочь ТС-у, то напишите просто ABC вариант решения задачи

Comment: @MDJHD не хочу помогать TC-y, хочу извлекать радугу из компилятора, написанием сверхъёмких выражений.

Comment: IMHO проще развернуть алгоритм в 2 цикла (а не делать все проверки в одном).


В первом ищем первый отрицательный. Как только нашли присваиваем его  переменной `max_negative`, `break` и ко второму. 

Второй цикл (очевидно) со следующего после первого отрицательного и до конца массива.

Если `max_negative` остался 0 -- сообщаем, что отрицательных нет.

Comment: @avp, в чем выигрышь двух циклов? По идее одном тоже, что за один проход, только код больше по строчками.

Comment: @pincher1519, в логической простоте.

Пока это просто покажет ТС, что можно (и нужно) делить программу на такие части, решение которых по отдельности не представляет проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Вот простое и элегантное решение. На С, но это несущественно, по большому счёту весь его смысл в ифе. Должен же ТС хоть что-то сделать сам? Пусть хоть на шарп переведёт. Подозреваю, что для него даже это не тривиально.

```
int array[10] = {
    0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9
};

int max_negative(void)
{
    int max = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        if( array[i] < 0 && ( max == 0 || array[i] > max ) ) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = max_negative();
    if( n == 0 ) {
        puts("No negative numbers.");
    } else {
        printf("max negative = %d\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: >В очередной раз поражаюсь, как местные профессионалы любят усложнять себе жизнь. Один в два прохода ищет, другой нагромоздил ифов несуразных.

не надо, пожалуйста, снисходительного тона. Вы-то чем хвастаетесь? Тем, что осилили элементарную задачку, решив ее самым очевидным способом? Уверяю, любой из "местных профессионалов" запросто сделал бы то же самое. Вопрос в том, что мало кому тут интересно такими способами решать такие задачки. 
Кстати, вы даже не удосужились внимательно прочесть условие, где сказано, что массив представляет собой матрицу n*n. Это несколько отличается от вашего случая

Comment: ого, кто-то еще отбивает пробелами выражение в control structure, но не отбивает сам control structure.

Comment: > Уверяю, любой из "местных профессионалов" запросто сделал бы то же самое. Вопрос в том, что мало кому тут интересно такими способами решать такие задачки.

А должно быть интересно делать именно так. Хороший код самоочевиден и является самому себе комментарием.

> Кстати, вы даже не удосужились внимательно прочесть условие, где сказано, что массив представляет собой матрицу n*n. Это несколько отличается от вашего случая

Позор на мою седую бороду! Это же меняет всю логику программы и делает моё решение неприменимым.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, не знаю, как в шарпе, а в Си IMHO вполне применимо 

(только, если речь о квадратной матрице, 10 надо на квадрат какого-нибудь натурального числа заменить (ну, и само-собой, основательно приподнять уровень ТС)).

Comment: >А должно быть интересно делать именно так

еще раз - это элементарная школьная задача.Решать ее в лоб априори мало кому интересно.

>Позор на мою седую бороду! Это же меняет всю логику программы и делает моё решение неприменимым

нет, речь не об этом. Речь о том, что громче всех кричать и катить на кого-то просто так бочку, дескать, смотрите, все тут валенком деланы, а я молодец - это как-то некрасиво, несолидно и не дает вам ничего, кроме дурной репутации. Особенно учитывая, что ваше решение неидеально (раз уж других упрекаете, то и сами должны соответствовать своим же высоким стандартам)

Comment: Есть такая игра - покер. Азартной не является, что бы там ни говорил Мутько. С тем же успехом он мог принять закон, что число пи является отрицательным. Доказательство очень простое - всем раздают одни и те же карты, с той же вероятностью. А знаете, почему одни в покере выигрывают (на дистанции, конечно), а другие проигрывают? Потому что одним интересно, а для других это лишь тупая, нудная работа. Например, если у Вас флэш-дро на тёрне, то вероятность, что оно закроется на ривере, 19%. Если нам надо заплатить меньше четверти банка - платим. Больше - не платим. И так ВСЕГДА. Скукотища, правда?

Comment: Я думал, Вы хоть с помощью аналогии поймёте. Не нужны никому всякие хитрые фокусы и жутко умные способы решения задач. К сожалению, есть у многих программистов своеобразный азарт. Ну неохота им делать "как надо". Скукотища! Хочется разнообразить всё это, напридумывать велосипедов, или решить задачу так, чтобы все глянули на исходник и ахнули. Или чтобы никто не мог понять, как это работает. Круто же!

И точно так же, как в покере, в программировании достигают успеха зануды, которые раз за разом предпринимают очевидные действия, а не выпрыгивает из штанов, чтобы кому-то (себе?) что-то доказать

Comment: @VadimTukaev, все-то вы наперед знаете.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, а преферанс (в покер-то я не играю) азартная игра?

Comment: @VadimTukaev вы почему-то тоже не торопитесь понять одну очевидную мысль, которую я пытаюсь донести до вас уже в третий раз - ваша крикливость и заносчивость, с которой вы провозгласили свой ответ совершенно не делает вам чести. Это просто некрасиво. Побольше уважения к коллегам по цеху. Более того, "местные профессионалы" не опубликовали очевидный вариант не потому что они такие глупые, а вы один такой умный, а по другим причинам (правильным или нет, другой вопрос)

Comment: > а преферанс (в покер-то я не играю) азартная игра?

Нет. Точно так же, как дурак, бридж... Да, и нарды! Всё это так называемые игры мастерства. То есть человек, играющий лучше, на дистанции будет иметь более высокое математическое ожидание выигрыша.

> "местные профессионалы" не опубликовали очевидный вариант не потому что они такие глупые

Ткните пальцем, где я назвал их глупыми? Я лишь указал на избыточную сложность их решений, а своё решение назвал простым. Вы с этим согласились, назвав мой код очевидным. Ну так в чём проблема? Радуйтесь, что Вы умнее меня и умеете писать неочевидный код

Comment: Пожалуйста, избегайте расширенного обсуждения в комментариях, их невозможно читать в данном случае. По поводу ответа- не является ответом на вопрос, данный алгоритм предназначен для одномерных массивов заданной размерности, тогда как в условии ясно сказано- двумерный массив динамичной размерности.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter n:");
        var n = GetNumber();
        var array = new int[n,n];
        var random = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("\nRandom array:");
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
            var el = (random.Next(0, 100) - 60);
            var length = el.ToString().Length;
            array[i, j] = el;
            Console.Write((length == 1 ? "  " + el :
                length == 2 ? " " + el :
                    el.ToString()) + (j + 1 == n ? "": ", "));
        }

        var maxNegative = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if (array[i, j] < maxNegative){
                    maxNegative = array[i, j];
                }       
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nMax negative number is " + maxNegative);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int GetNumber()
    {
        var n = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect value, enter n:");
            n = GetNumber();
        };
        return n;
    }
}
```

[image: Результат работы программы]